# Finding the mean of all number in a range given by the user

Tags: c++

Program is supposed to allow the user to input 2 integers and find the mean of all the integers between (and including) the two given by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value1, value2;
    int total = 0;
    int number = 1;       // the amount of numbers
    float mean;

    cout << "Please enter two positive integers separated by a space" << endl;
    cin >> value1; cin >> value2;

    if (value1 > 0 && value2 > 0)
    {
        for (int total = value1; total <= value2; total++)
        {
            mean = static_cast<float>(total) / number;
        }
        cout << "The mean average of the numbers between and including "
             << value1 << " and " << value2
             << " is " << mean << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input - integer must be positive" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Currently mean just ends up repeating the second number. How far off am I here?

Comment: Arithmetic mean of the positive integers in (m, n) is `(m+n)/2.0`

Comment: Wouldn't that be `[m, n]`? This code assumes `value2` is greater than `value1`. We only know that both numbers are greater than 0. The formula provided doesn't require that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for-loop.  You can compute mean as:

```
mean = (value1 + value2)/2.0;
```

Done.

Otherwise, the bugs in your program are as follows:

First `number` is only ever assigned the value 1.

Second, you are redeclaring `total` as a for loop variable as well as an outer variable. You only need to declare it once.  The compiler should have warned you.

Third:

```
    for (int total = value1; total <= value2; total++)
    {
        mean = static_cast<float>(total) / number;
    }
```

In the above you are continually reassigning a new value to `mean` on each iteration instead of letting it accumulate.  Also `mean` is never initialized before the for loop. Probably want to set it to zero.

Finally, you're not handling the case where a user enters a bigger number for value1 than value2.

I think you really meant this:

```
    if (value1 > value2)
    {
        int tmp = value2;
        value2 = value;
        value1 = tmp;
    }
    number = value2-value1+1;
    mean = 0.0f;

    for (total = value1; total <= value2; total++)
    {
        mean += static_cast<float>(total) / number;
    }
```

But again, unless my math is off, the above is simplified to:

```
 mean = (value1+value2)/2.0;
```

Comment: I'm actually attempting to get the program to give the mean of a range of numbers, the upper and lower number are set by the user e.g. user inputs 1 and 5: mean =
(1+2+3+4+5) / 5

Comment: `(1+2+3+4+5) / 5` is the exact same as `(1+5)/2`.  Both expressions equal `3`.  Isn't math neat?

Comment: @Ryan - Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I've edited my answer and undeleted it to explain why **it sucked** and why **selbie**'s answer is correct.

As **selbie** pointed out, the mean of all integers in `[m, n]` is `(m + n)/2`.

*To undestand why, let's step through my previously unnecessary complicated answer.*

---

> The sum of all integers in `(0, n]` is `n*(n + 1)/2`.
> Assuming that `n > m`, to know the sum of all the integers in `(m, n]` just subtract the sum of all the integers in `(0, m]`, i.e.: `(n*(n + 1)/2 - m*(m + 1)/2)`
> To know the sum of all integers in `[m, n]`, we must use `m1 = m - 1`
>
> Once you know the sum the mean is simply `sum/(n - m1)`

---

It works, but it sucks because the right answer is way easier.
The nice thing is that from my inefficient answer is possible to derive the good one.

Let's consider
`n = m + k`
`m1 = m - 1`

and replace them in the equation `(n*(n + 1)/2 - m1*(m1 + 1)/2)/(n - m1)`

I factorized both `/ 2` and replaced them with `* 0.5` outside.
The resulting sequence of simplifications is

```
( ( (m + k)*(m + k + 1) - (m - 1)*(m - 1 + 1) ) * 0.5 ) / ( m + k - m + 1)

( ( m2 + km + km + k2 + m + k - m2 + m ) * 0.5 ) / ( k + 1 )

( ( 2km + 2m + k2 + k ) * 0.5 ) / ( k + 1 )

( ( 2m(k + 1) + k(k + 1) ) * 0.5 ) / ( k + 1 )

( (2m + k) * (k + 1) * 0.5 ) / ( k + 1 )

( 2m + k ) * 0.5

( m + k + m ) / 2

( m + n ) / 2
```

Which is exactly the average of `value1` and `value2`